# Linear approximation of multivariate function of bounded second order partial derivatives

Tags: approximation-theory, taylor-series

I have a question about linear approximation in the multivariate case.\

Let $f:B^d_r\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued $C^2$-function defined on the $d$-dimensional ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin.
Assume further that $\frac{\partial ^2f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}<C$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2,3,...,d\}$ where $C$ is a constant.

I am interested in the max-error $\sup_{\mathbf{x}\in B^d_r}|f(\mathbf{x})-P_1(\mathbf{x})|$ where $P_1(x)$ is a first order multivariate polynomial.

I know from Taylors theorem we have

\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{0})+\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{0})x_i + \sum_{|\mathbf{\alpha}|=2}R_{\mathbf{\alpha}}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{x}^{\alpha}
\end{align}

where $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $|\mathbf{\alpha}|=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_d$ and $\mathbf{x}^{\mathbf{\alpha}}=x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}...x_d^{\alpha_d}$.

We can also bound $R_{\mathbf{\alpha}}(\mathbf{x})\leq \frac{1}{\mathbf{\alpha}!}C$.

Thus if we choose $P_1(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{0})+\nabla f(\mathbf{0})\cdot \mathbf{x}$
then
\begin{align}
|f(\mathbf{x})-P_1(\mathbf{x})|\leq \sum_{|\alpha|=2}\frac{1}{\alpha !}C\mathbf{x}^{\alpha}
\end{align}
Im not sure how to proceed from here.
Of course I can say that $\mathbf{x}^{\alpha}\leq r^2$ for each term since $|\alpha|=2$ and similarly $\frac{1}{\alpha!}\leq 1$ so I would get:

$|f(\mathbf{x})-P_1(\mathbf{x})|\leq \frac{(d+1)d}{2}Cr^2$
as there are exactly $\frac{(d+1)d}{2}$ multi-indices $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=2$.

**My questions**:

1. **Can this bound be improved?**
2. **Especially, is it necessary to get the dimension $d$ into the estimate?**

Kind regards

Comment: For $r=1$ and $x=d^{-1/2}(1,1,\ldots,1)$ you have $\sum_{j,k=1}^d |x_jx_k|= d$. There does not seem to be reasonnable bound independent of the dimension.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thanks, but maybe it is possible to get a linear dependence on $d$ instead of a quadratic one that I obtained above?

Comment: Did you try to maximize $\sum x_jx_k$ subject to $\sum x_j^2=1$?

Comment: I tried it now but cant manage to solve it using lagrange multipliers

Comment: $\sum_{j.k} x_j x_k =\left(\sum_k x_k\right)^2$ should help.

Comment: Thanks! Well, then I guess (if i have done it correctly) that the maximum value is the dimension d? Doest it seem correct?